# Elasticsearch Script - Unexpected characters

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to update a doc using painless scripts. My document contain fields like `"a4ayc/8"` (the field name contains the character `/`).

**Document sample:**

```
   {
        "_index" : "user_profile",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "SQ9/X1iKV7DDJXJLLMAvyt",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "TgdAhWI" : "text",
          "a4ayc/8" : 1,
          "SyJ3d9Q" : true,
          "qBC0wbU" : "2021-05-25T14:22:40.804Z"
        }
      }
```

Executing the following script i get an exception for the `"a4ayc/8"` field:

> [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=invalid assignment: cannot
> assign a value to division operation [/]]

**Script:**

```
{
       "script":{
          "source":"ctx._source.TgdAhWI = params.param1; ctx._source.qBC0wbU = params.param2; ctx._source.a4ayc/8 = params.param3; ctx._source.SyJ3d9Q = params.param4; ",
          "lang":"painless",
          "params":{
             "param3":1,
             "param4":true,
             "param1":"text",
             "param2":"2021-05-25T14:22:40.804Z"
          }
       },
       "upsert":{
          "TgdAhWI":"text",
          "a4ayc/8":1,
          "SyJ3d9Q":true,
          "qBC0wbU":"2021-05-25T14:22:40.804Z"
       }
    }
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to reference the field differently, like this:

```
ctx._source['a4ayc/8'] = params.param3
```

And it would be the same thing if your field name starts with a number because it would not be a [valid Painless identifier](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.12/painless-identifiers.html), e.g.

```
ctx._source['4a4ayc8'] = params.param3
```